# show the result of two date range?

Tags: mysql

I want the result available rooms between two dates for both rooms.

My query

```
SELECT * 
FROM `roomcalendar` 
WHERE day BETWEEN '2016-08-29' and '2016-08-31'
```

Result
[image]

This query does not show any result.

```
select * 
FROM roomcalendar 
WHERE day between '2016-08-30' and '2016-08-31' 
AND avaroom != 0 having count(*) = datediff('2016-08-31','2016-08-30')
```

I can use where roomname='Room-A' but I don't want to use it. Any other method to get the both available rooms between two dates with room name?

Comment: you have no `group by`, so your `count(*)` is indeterminate.

Comment: @MarcB Can you show how to use with group by. ? Thanks.

Comment: any idea to get the result of roomname. it always show only one result.

Comment: no idea, but random guess: `group by roomname`?

Comment: yes i use group by but it show only one result of Room-A or Room-B.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly what you need might be something like:

```
SELECT r.roomname, SUM(r.avaroom) as availableRooms
FROM roomcalendar r
WHERE DAY BETWEEN '2016-08-29' AND '2016-08-31'
GROUP BY r.roomname
```

It I'll give you:

```
+----------+----------------+
| roomname | availableRooms |
+----------+----------------+
| Room-A   |              5 |
| Room-B   |              4 |
+----------+----------------+
```

Is this what you want?

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT * 
FROM `roomcalendar` r
WHERE DAY BETWEEN '2016-08-29' AND '2016-08-31' AND r.`avaroom`>0
ORDER BY r.`day`
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!